# Having trouble making a list of lists of a designated size

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to make a list of lists of about 5000 lists and it keeps messing up.
right now I just do this:

```
array = [[]]*5000
for line in f2:
    a = line.split()
    grid = int(a[0])
    array[grid].append(a[1])

print Counter(array[0]).most_common(10)
```

the problem is when I make the counter it does it as if the whole array of lists was actually just one list.  Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Using `[[]]*5000`, you are creating *5000* reference to the same list in your outer list. So, if you modify any list, it will modify all of them.

You can get different lists like this:

```
a = [[] for _ in xrange(5000)]
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate to about 1000 other Python questions where the list of lists is initialized this way. I think we need "Frequently Answered Answers", and then we can just say "See FAA #27" or whatever. Other candidates: "Syntax error on line N means unmatched parentheses on line N-1", "Comparing 1 < '0' will not give the result you think it will, because they are different types". Hm, I think I'll post a new Community Wiki question...