# How to create a matrix with values as dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matrix

To create a matrix whose **values are lists** I normally do the following:

```
T = [[0]*(4) for x in range(4)]
print T
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I am trying to create a matrix whose **values are dictionaries** , I try the same thing and I get problem.

```
T = [{"first":None,"second":None} *(4) for x in range(4)]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'int'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Intention:

At each T[i][j] , I am trying to record the values picked by first player and second player in a game round (i,j).

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, my lists version is right. I get the desired output.[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: The values there aren't lists but ints.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6667288

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define two-dimensional array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan No my question is different. I want a two-dimensional array with values in each T[i][j] as dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should write:

```
T = [[{"first":None,"second":None} for y in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
print T
```

`

```
[[{'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None},
{'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None}],
 [{'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None},
 {'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None}], 
[{'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None}, 
{'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None}], 
[{'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None},
 {'second': None, 'first': None}, {'second': None, 'first': None}]]`
```

Reason you can't do:

```
T = [[{"first":None,"second":None}]*4 for x in range(4)]
```

is the same as the reason you can't do:

```
T = [[[1]]*4 for x in range(4)]
```

When you write `*` you are essentially repeating the same object given number of times. So, if you update one of the entries all the entries in that row will get updated as they are all the same object.

This doesn't happen in case of :
    `T = [[0]*4 for x in range(4)]`

as `0` is an int and you replace it completely when you assign a new value at any place. You can find better explanation in some other SO answers. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411892/having-trouble-making-a-list-of-lists-of-a-designated-size), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946728/changing-an-element-in-one-list-changes-multiple-lists)

For dictionaries `+` and `*` are not supported. If this answers your problem then you should do more research before posting a question. Otherwise, please elaborate.

Comment: I already tried this. when i try to update.T[0][0]["first"] = 2
T[0][0]["second"] = 3  the entire first list gets updated. which i dont want. I want just the first dic at T[0][0] to get updated.

Comment: Ohh, right my mistake I will update with explanation.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thankyou... Now I am able to reference T[0][0]["first"] = 2
T[0][0]["second"] = 3

T[0][1]["first"] = 4 and get necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

if you want a dictionary with 4 unique keys you need to have a generator making the keys as well:

EDIT - removed `*(4)` from copied code

```
T = [{i:None for i in range(4)} for x in range(4)]
```

do take note that the keys of a dictionary do not strictly have to be strings, this makes the keys ints so it would work very similarly to any code meant to support the version using lists

Comment: actually you might as well do `T = {x:{i:None for i in range(4)} for x in range(4)}` while you are at it...

Comment: For the answer you suggested I am still getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'int'"

Comment: my bad, copied from your's and forgot to remove that :P now it works

Comment: I just looked at the question again and based on the _intention_ this will not solve the problem, this will make each row a dict instead of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the other answers do not give you what you exactly want, which is how to hack on things to make them behave the way you want to.

Since the **dict** class does not have an **imul** numeric type to deal with multiplication operation, we can simply create our own class which does that for us.

```
a = { 'first': None , 'second': None }

class MultDict:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        lst = []
        for i in range(other):
            lst.append(a.copy())
        return lst

x = MultDict()

t = [ x * (4) for i in range(4)]

print(t)

t[0][0]['first']=2
print(t)
```

Output:

```
[[{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}],
[{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}],
[{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}],
[{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}]] 


[[{'first': 2, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}],
[{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}],
[{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}],
[{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None},
{'first': None, 'second': None}]]
```